# List of Printers in classic ASP/VB Script

Tags: asp-classic

Is there a way to get the list of installed printers in classic ASP?

Answer (score 0):

No, your code run in the browser sandbox and can't access local hardware (except using Flash, Activex or Silverlight)

Comment: ASP doesn't run in the "browser sandbox".  ASP runs on the server.

Comment: as asp runs on the server you probably could get a list of installed printers on the server but that is not waht aou want, right?